# Mapping and object to objectDto in angular 10

Tags: angular, rest, dictionary, model, webapi

I am struggling to map an object that come from my webapi to an objectDto in my Angular 10. I want to map an new field in Dto , etatIcon.

How to do that?

This is my object that come from the WebApi

```
{
    "idAlerte": 1,
    "codeType": "ACQ",
    "codeEtat": "YZ"   
}
```

My model.ts in Angular

```
export interface ISosAlerte {
    idAlerte: number;
    codeType: string;
    codeEtat: string;
    etatIcon: string;
}

export class SosAlerte implements ISosAlerte{ 
    idAlerte: number;
    codeType: string;
    codeEtat: string;
    etatIcon: string;

    constructor(
         idAlerte: number = null,
         codeType: string = '',
         codeEtat: string = '',
         etatIcon: string = ''
    )
    {
        this.idAlerte=idAlerte;
        this.codeType=codeType;
        this.codeEtat=codeEtat;

        if(this.codeType ==="ACQ")
            this.etatIcon = './../../../assets/images/red.png';
        else
            this.etatIcon = './../../../assets/images/green.png';
    }
}
```

I Load this value in my service.ts

```
  public alertEnCours: SosAlerte[] = [];

  public load(): Observable<boolean> {
    this.isBusy = true;
    if (this.isLoaded) {
                        return new Observable((observer) => {
                          this.isBusy = false;
                          observer.next(true);
                          observer.complete();
                        });
    } else {
            return this.httpClient.get(this.ENDPOINT_URL,this.httpOptions)
            .pipe(  
                    catchError(this.handleError),          
                    map((data: SosAlerte[]) => { 
                      this.isBusy = false;                  
                      this.alertEnCours = data;   <== Here I never have the etatIcon mapped
                      this.isLoaded = true;                    
                      return true;
                    }),
                  );
    }
  }
```

Comment: From what I see you're never invoking the constructor of `SosAlerte`, so how should the mapping happen? And shouldn't be `SosAlerte[]` the return type of `map()` rather than the type of incoming data?

Comment: I guess you should trying something like this in your `map()` callback: `this.alertEnCours = data.map(item => new SosAlerte(item))`

Comment: Thanks you Ibsn. Its working now. I am still learning.